# Which values can matrices hold?

Tags: matrices

Is it possible for a matrix to contain values other than numbers, e.g. vectors? I have seen matrices that contain complex numbers, but can they contain more complicated mathematical objects as well? If so, would each item have to be the same type e.g. would a matrix containing both vectors and numbers make sense or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define a matrix, and what you want to use a matrix for. The simplest definition of a matrix is simply as a rectangular array of objects. Here they can be any sort of object; symbols, variables, polynomials vectors, etc. If you want to be able to add matrices, or multiply them by scalars, then this needs to make sense for the objects you are putting in as entries.

If all you want to use the matrix for is to hold values, then you of course don't need restrictions. If you want your matrices to form a vector space over some field, or to represent some sort of linear transformation, then there needs to be a way to interpret the "entries" of the matrix in a way that allows this.